Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (FLUTTER)
I get this error when running my flutter application.
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugManifest'.


Could not create task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.`

I have tried flutter clean and flutter pub cache clean but to no avail. I have also updated the compileSdkVersion to 34 and I am using gradle version of 7.6.2-all. How do I resolve this issue please. I have tried many answers online but still doesn't work for me.
Below are some screenshots and flutter doctor output to give more context
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3880], locale en-GH)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at C:\Users\d.partey\Documents\Development\flutter sdks\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (7 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\d.partey\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-VanillaIceCream, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\d.partey\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3880]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.182
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 126.0.2592.113

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

Below is my manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="world.opine.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Opine World"
        tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="opine.world"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="opine.world"
                    android:scheme="opine" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EmbeddingV1Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${geoApiKEY}" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>

android/build.gradle
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
     ext.ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
     ext {
       compileSdkVersion   = 34                // or latest
       targetSdkVersion    = 34                // or latest
       appCompatVersion    = "1.7.0"           // or latest
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
         maven {
            // [required] background_fetch
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// subprojects {
//     project.configurations.all {
//  resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
//             if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core' &&
//         !details.requested.name.contains('androidx')) {
//      details.useVersion "1.0.1"
//             }
//  }
//     }

// }

// subprojects {
//   afterEvaluate { subproject ->
//     if (subproject.hasProperty("android")) {
//       android {
//         compileSdkVersion 27
//         buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
//       }
//     }
//   }
// }

app/build.gradle
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    throw GradleException("versionCode not found. Define flutter.versionCode in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    throw GradleException("versionName not found. Define flutter.versionName in the local.properties file.")
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def geoApiKEY = localProperties.getProperty('geo.apiKEY')

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "world.opine.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [geoApiKEY: geoApiKEY]
    }

    signingConfigs {
    release {
        // if (System.getenv()["CI"]) { // CI=true is exported by Codemagic
        //     storeFile file(System.getenv()["CM_KEYSTORE_PATH"])
        //     storePassword System.getenv()["CM_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
        //     keyAlias System.getenv()["CM_KEY_ALIAS"]
        //     keyPassword System.getenv()["CM_KEY_PASSWORD"]
        // } else {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            // storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storeFile file("Users/Kwabena/key.jks")
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        // }
    }
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        //  minifyEnabled true
//             useProguard true

        // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        // android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        //     variant.outputs.all {
        //         outputFileName = "opine-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}-${variant.versionCode}.apk"
        //     }
        // }
    }
}

android {
    namespace 'world.opine.app'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
    lint {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    // buildTypes {
    //     release {
    //         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
    //         // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
    //         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

    //         minifyEnabled true
    //         useProguard true

    //         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    //     }
    // }

// splits {
//         // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
//         abi {
//             // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
//             enable true
//             // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
//             // want APKs for armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.

//             // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
//             reset()

//             // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
//             // include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
//             include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"

//             // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
//             universalApk false
//         }
//     }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    // api "androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha04"
}


It seems to be related to the java version
Try changing
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

to
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}


Thank you for the answer. I tried it but it still gave the same error response

Sorry, I re-read your error message, which says "value" is null. Look carefully at the code. The source of geoApiKEY is localProperties.getProperty('geo.apiKEY'), but there is no local in the code you gave. .properties related code, so I reasonably suspect that there may not be geoApiKEY in local.properties

Thank you. This solved the issue. I created a the geo.apiKEY in the local properties
